# How can I make a textView size dynamic, according to the content in it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm made a `CustomCell` for my `tableView` which expands and contracts when it is tapped. And when in expand state it shows a `textView`. I save my values in an array of Dictionary and then print it in my `tableView` according to particular cell. But my `textView` in the cell has the size fixed, how do I change the size according to the content of that particular dictionary ? Here is my code of `CustomCell`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell, BEMCheckBoxDelegate {
var isObserving = false;

class var expandedHeight: CGFloat { get { return 100 } }
class var defaultHeight: CGFloat  { get { return 40 } }

func checkHeight() {
    textView.isHidden = (frame.size.height < CustomCell.expandedHeight)

}
func watchFrameChanges() {
    if !isObserving {
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, NSKeyValueObservingOptions.initial], context: nil)
        isObserving = true;
    }
}

func ignoreFrameChanges() {
    if isObserving {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")
        isObserving = false;
    }
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "frame"{
        checkHeight()
    }
}
```

And the code of class which has `tableView`:

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCellID") as! CustomCell
    cell.textView.text = arrOfDict[indexPath.row]["notesField"] as! String!
    return (cell)
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath
        {
        return CustomCell.expandedHeight

    }
    else {
        return CustomCell.defaultHeight
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        (cell as! CustomCell).watchFrameChanges()

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as! CustomCell).ignoreFrameChanges()

}


override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [CustomCell] {
        cell.ignoreFrameChanges()
    }
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }

        var indexPaths : Array<IndexPath> = []
        if let previous = previousIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [previous]
        }
        if let current = selectedIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [current]
        }
        if indexPaths.count > 0 {
            tableView.reloadData()

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case with default and expected height use **autolayout**.

Example create custom cell. With `heightConstraint` outlet to the constraint.

```
class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var isExpanded:Bool = false
        {
        didSet
        {
            if !isExpanded {
                self.imgHeightConstraint.constant = 40.0

            } else {
                self.imgHeightConstraint.constant = 100.0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for the `tableView`.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Then implement `estimatedHeightForRowAt` and return expected height.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 40.0

}
```

Now when you select cell implement method `didSelectRowAt`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? ExpandableCell

            else { return }
        

        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        self.tableView.endUpdates()   
}
```

Comment: my cell view doesnt seem to expand now.

Comment: How you set constraint ?

Comment: I added a constraint of height to my `textView` then dragged it into my `CustomCell`

Comment: It should be height of the Cell

Comment: it is not allowing me to add constraint to my cell. https://s13.postimg.org/wu69wpyon/upload.jpg

Comment: @S.Verma try to read this article http://codepany.com/blog/swift-3-expandable-table-view-cells/